# Use zoomid in another function after I get its value

Tags: jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {

         var zoomid;

         $('img[id^=bx-gallery-icon-]').on('click', function () {

                 var zoomid = this.id.replace('bx-gallery-icon-', '#bx-gallery-img-');

             });

         $(zoomid).addimagezoom({
                 zoomrange: [1, 10]
             });
     });
</script>
```

I trying to use the var 'zoomid' on the second function, but I cant figure out how to carry it, with the on - click...

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var zoomid;
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('img[id^=bx-gallery-icon-]').on('click', function () {
      zoomid = this.id.replace('bx-gallery-icon-', '#bx-gallery-img-'); 
   }); 
   $(zoomid).addimagezoom({ zoomrange: [1, 10] });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the try, but if that was going to work, alert( zoomid ) would hold a value. The problem I'm facing is, I can't move $(zoomid).addimagezoom({ zoomrange: [1, 10] }); up inside .on('click as it throws my page out, because it adds .addimagezoom to the wrong div... something like this works perfect though $('#bx-gallery-img-1').addimagezoom({ zoomrange: [1, 10] });